# Missing tree structure icons

Tags: asp.net

I have written a CMS system using visual studio and the standard tree structure. Locally it looks fine but on my live system the '+' icons are missing and there is just the usual 'missing image' icon which does not allow the tree to open.

Can anyone tell me where the '+' icons are found so that I could replace them?